# Mysql save emoji as '?'

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, emoji

I have a spring boot project (2.4.5) with mysql (mysql-connector-java), and when I try to save a text with emoji, the db saves as a question mark (?).

After some search, I've already try to alter db and tables enconde with:

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY field_name TEXT CHARSET utf8mb4;
```

But no success.

Also, tried to set Hikari connection with this:

```
spring:
  datasource:
     hikari:
        connection-init-sql: SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Here is my hibernate logs:

```
2021-06-17 08:12:55,244 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger: 
    insert 
    into
        post
        (img_url, posted_date, text, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        post
        (img_url, posted_date, text, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)
2021-06-17 08:12:55,244 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2021-06-17 08:12:55,245 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2021-06-17T08:12:55.197196]
2021-06-17 08:12:55,245 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - []
2021-06-17 08:12:55,245 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - [105]
```

And table DDL:

```
-- post definition

CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_by` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified_by` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified_date` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `img_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `posted_date` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK72mt33dhhs48hf9gcqrq4fxte` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK72mt33dhhs48hf9gcqrq4fxte` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKbbelhmvq5tsjie489mqfqsqao` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `timeline` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=106 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Entity:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Post extends Timeline {

    private String text;
    private String img_url;
    private LocalDateTime postedDate;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post")
    private List<PostComment> comments;


    public Post(User loggedUser, String text, String imgURL, LocalDateTime now) {
        this.setUser(loggedUser);
        this.setText(text);
        this.setImg_url(imgURL);
        this.setPostedDate(now);
        this.setType(TimelineTypeEnum.POST);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Post{" +
                "text='" + text + '\'' +
                ", img_url='" + img_url + '\'' +
                ", postedDate=" + postedDate +
                ", comments=" + null +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add your entity mapping ?

Comment: Where is "text with emoji" ?

Comment: I receive the text from the frontend on my API (controller).  Could be any emoji.

Comment: you can give me an example of this text on your front and debug your controller to verify if it is the same content ?

Comment: it could be any text with the emoji, and it will be save just like it, but the emoji replaced by question mark. 
eg:  I like it  
will be saved as: I like it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the parameter `CharacterEncoding=UTF-8` like below.

application.yml:

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
     jdbc-url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/[YOUR_DB_NAME_HERE]?serverTimeZone=UTC&CharacterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Happy Coding!